# how to get textbox value from a gridview control in a webpage using C#

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox

I tried the below code for fetching values from text box present in gridview but the text value shows blank "".

what's the issue with this code??
`TextBox box1 = (TextBox)grdCountry.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox1");`

design code :
 `<asp:gridview ID="grdCountry" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" 
     AutoGenerateColumns="false">
     <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryName"  HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate> 
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                           </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>`

Comment: Drop the `Cells[0]` part, just searching inside the row should work. But when are you running this?

Comment: Tried that but to no avail. Didn't get this 'But when are you running this?'

Comment: In context of ASP.NET "when" almost always refers to page life cycle. Do you run it after postback occurred? In which page event, or control even handler?

Comment: I run it after postback. On click of button  I am trying to save the textbox data into database.So i am running the code on button click control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved.The above code works properly.I was refreshing the whole page hence the data stored in textbox was showing blank data.

Answer (score 0):

Try define a name for textbox, and in c# use "nameTextBox.Text();"

Comment: I don't think there is an option for naming the textbox other than the id